# Total stardust doesn't refresh at first power up. Is this a bug?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've noticed that the total amount of stardust doesn't refresh immediately when I power up a pokemon. I have either to power it up for a second time or switch to another pokemon to see the total stardust amount being refreshed.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Note: Powering up for a second time doesn't work most of the time. I'm not sure if I've misobserved it before. Last night I did power up some of my pokemons for a second time. I saw that the total stardust amount did not refresh.

Comment: It could just be a latency issue with syncing up with the servers. I've noticed that the CP will sometimes reset on power up temporarily, but will be back to what it should be shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a bug and the same thing occurs on my iPhone. I would recommend looking at the known bugs page (accessible via "report high priority issue" within the app) to see if it has been reported already. If it's not reported, create the issue yourself.